# How does one do collision detection without a fixed timestep?

Tags: collision-detection, game-physics

I am doing a Bomberman clone with simple collision detection. Theoretically, if the game hiccups for a second, that second gets passed in as the delta time and the collision detection may not even see the block that was in the way if the move to location is valid. Is a fixed time step the solution to this problem or is there another algorithm or way simple collision with rectangles is handled that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

For a simple 2D game, I think a fixed time step would be the simplest answer. If movement continues while the processing hangs, the player won't be able to take evasive action if needed, and will get frustrated.

However, you could modify the bounding rectangles of your objects based on their speed and then subdivide the time interval if you detect a collision.

For example, if an object has a bounding rect of `{y_top,y_bottom,x_left,x_right}` and is moving at a speed of `{delta_x,delta_y}` per second, then in time `t`, the distance moved is `{delta_x * t, delta_y * t}`, and a bounding rect for collision detection can be calculated as follows:

```
if (delta_x < 0) {
    x_left = x_left + delta_x * t
} else {
    x_right = x_right + delta_x * t
}

if (delta_y < 0) {
    y_bottom = y_bottom + delta_y * t
} else {
    y_top = y_top + delta_y * t
}
```